# How to stop jQuery post page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, refresh

I am getting data from an MySQL database through PHP. I am sending the and getting the data from PHP using jQuery. Here is the code.

```
$.POST("SubmitCode.php", $("#questionCodeForm").serialize(),'json').done(function(data) {});
```

Now the problem is that once I send this data the page refreshes. How can I stop the page refresh. If I delete 'json' then the page stops refreshing but the problem is that I want to get the json data without page refresh. How can I do this?

-------------------------------------------after edit-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Here is the updated code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initialization();

    codeSubmission();
});

function initialization() {
    $("#answerForm").hide();
}

function codeSubmission() {
  $("#submitButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("SubmitCode.php", $("#questionCodeForm").serialize()).done(function(data) {
        var questionName = data.questionName,
            options = data.options,
            pollingStatus = data.pollingStatus,
            codeExist = data.codeExist;

        alert(data);
        alert(data[1]);
        alert(questionName);
        alert(options);

        if(codeExist == true) {
            $("#questionTitle").text("questionName");

            for(rowNum=1;rowNum<=5;rowNum++) {
                $("#checkbox-"+rowNum).val("Answer1");
                $("#checkbox"+rowNum+"label").text("Answer"+rowNum);
            } 

            $("#answerForm").slideDown(500);

        } else if(codeExist == false) {
            alert("This quiz code is invalid");
        }   
    },'json');  
    //return false;
  });
    //return false;
}
```

Now the problem is that the output of alert(questionName) is undefined. The data is passed as a string. How do I get the correct information in the correct variables?

Comment: That edit is really another question, rather than an update on this one.  However - are you sending JSON data (use `echo json_encode($yourArray);` in PHP, with no other output).

Comment: Yes that is correct. I am only echoing the variables through json

Comment: The error that appears briefly is: Uncaught TypeError: Object json has no method 'apply'

Comment: That error usually indicates the `$.post()` routine thinks the `'json'` parameter is the callback.  The problem is you've got the `'json'` string in the `.done()` call, not the `$.post()` call. It should be after the serialized data parameter.

Comment: found the answer. I have to parse the JSON on the client side using jQuery.parseJSON

Comment: jQuery does that for you automatically if you pass the parameter as I stated.  You just had it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to parse the json on the client side. You can do this using

obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:  (note the placement of the callback function, and lowercase .post method)

```
$.post("SubmitCode.php", $("#questionCodeForm").serialize(),function(data) {
  //manipulate your data here

 },'json');
```

Also make sure that whatever is triggering the post isn't an actual link and if it is, you need to stop the default action from occuring.  For example:

```
<a href="submit.php">Click here to submit</a>
```

javascript:

```
$(a).click(function(e) { 
e.preventDefault();
$.post("SubmitCode.php", $("#questionCodeForm").serialize(),function(data) {
  //manipulate your data here

 },'json');
});
```

Comment: I suspect the latter part of this is the key, using `.done()` is fine.

Comment: Note, you can just do `return false;` on jQuery event functions.

Comment: Using links to submit forms is dirty

Comment: I have updated the question. @Orbling, would using .done() solve the data problem above?

Comment: Let me know if you need to see the php file where the data is handled.

Comment: @meouw It was the simplest example to show how to prevent default behaviour.

Comment: @Orbling Unless you can show why using return false is *better* than e.preventDefault(), your comment is non constructive.  Since OP is not concerned with event bubbling, and just default behaviour, return false is not an improvement.

Comment: @VedaSadhak add the e.preventDefault() to your submit listener and it will stop the page from refreshing, we don't need to see the PHP file.

Comment: @meouw: It's exceptionally common, sometimes a convenience, besides, the `.click()` may well be on a submit button.

Comment: @RuralJuror: a) He was asking about a separate issue, so it might be needed to see the file. b) Your comment on `return false` is unnecessarily aggressive, it is a jQuery shorthand that is advised for stopping event bubbling, which includes a call to `preventDefault()` - it's a perfectly normal alternative.

Comment: @RuralJuror, the page refresh problem has been solved, however the problem that has started now is that the data is being passed as a string rather than json. So when I try to access the data from questionName I can't because its undefined.

Comment: @VedaSadhak: See my comment on the question.